# Caching versioned static files with ASP.NET MVC on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, caching, web-config

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="StaticFiles" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="StaticContent/[\d.]+/(.*)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="StaticContent/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

I am trying to add Caching versioned static files with ASP.NET MVC on IIS7.
I got  "The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'rewrite'" error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1564056.aspx/1) over at asp.net that may be of help. Als there is this [scottgu post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx). I hope those will get you on the right path.

Comment: thanks a lot Ashok. I forgot to install URL Rewrite module for IIS.